# Run a simple command using PowerShell recursively on a directory

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

What's the fastest way using either DOS scripting or PowerShell to run this simple command on a directory and all its subdirectories:

```
 convert filename.jpg -resize 620x620 "R:\processed\filename.jpg"
```

**DOS Batch script for single directory**:

```
 FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO convert %%a -resize 620x620 "R:\processed\%%a"
```

I want to run this recursively on a directory structure and have the output match the input hierarchy. I figured PowerShell was the easiest way, but I was unable to learn PowerShell in the 5 minutes I have to do this task!

Note: not that it's relevant, but `convert` is from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In PowerShell:

Use the -recurse switch and pipe to foreach. For e.g.:

```
dir -recurse -include *.jpg | %{convert  $_.FullName -resize 620x620 "R:\processed\$_"}
```

(Note that the % sign is an alias of foreach-object).

Comment: "R:\processed\ $_.Name" should be "R:\processed\$($_.Name)" to get the file name in the string.

Comment: @Emperor. Oops you're right. Actually you can use "R:\processed\$_" to get the same results.

Comment: currently this ends up trying to save in "R:\processed\R:\unprocessed\1.jpg because it doesnt take the relative path from the current directory. can this easily be found? using $_ is too much but $_.Name does not contain the path

Comment: Interesting, it works for me. $_.FullName returns the full path. $_.Name returns just the filename. $_ by itself should be the same as $_.Name since the string conversion of a FileInfo object is $_.Name. Maybe you can try @Emperor suggestion: "R:\processed\$($_.Name)"