# Run a command using PowerShell on each directory with an assumed path component

Tags: powershell

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784057/run-a-simple-command-using-powershell-recursively-on-a-directory), which is *very* similar to what I want but I just couldn't get it to work.

I want to run process.exe on each subdirectory's XML directory of C:\ToProcess. If I did it by hand, the first 6 of the 50 or so commands would look like this:

```
process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i "C:\ToProcess\abx\XML" -o "C:\Processed\abx\XML"
process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i "C:\ToProcess\dez\XML" -o "C:\Processed\dez\XML"
process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i "C:\ToProcess\ghm\XML" -o "C:\Processed\ghm\XML"
process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i "C:\ToProcess\jkq\XML" -o "C:\Processed\jkq\XML"
process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i "C:\ToProcess\mn0\XML" -o "C:\Processed\mn0\XML"
process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i "C:\ToProcess\pq2\XML" -o "C:\Processed\pq2\XML"
```

But before running those commands, I would have to do this, because the target folders do not yet exist:

```
md "C:\Processed\abx"
md "C:\Processed\dez"
md "C:\Processed\ghm"
md "C:\Processed\jkq"
md "C:\Processed\mn0"
md "C:\Processed\pq2"
md "C:\Processed\abx\XML"
md "C:\Processed\dez\XML"
md "C:\Processed\ghm\XML"
md "C:\Processed\jkq\XML"
md "C:\Processed\mn0\XML"
md "C:\Processed\pq2\XML"
```

So, is there a way to do all this in just a couple commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.  It will create each of the destination directories if they don't exist and then run process.exe on each.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ToProcess\*\XML | ForEach-Object { 
    $newPath = $_.FullName.Replace("ToProcess","Processed"); 
    New-Item $newPath -ItemType Directory  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;   
    .\process.exe -switch1 -switch2 -i $_.FullName -o $newPath;
}
```

Update: Added .\ before process following comment

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a single line?  If you can do this in a powershell script, then you could do something like the following:

```
foreach ($path in (get-childitem -recurse | foreach-object -process { if ($_.FullName.EndsWith("\xml")) {$_.FullName} }))
{
    $newpath = $path.Substring(0,$path.LastIndexOf("\xml"));
    $newpath = $newpath.Substring($newPath.LastIndexOf("\"));
    $newpath = "c:\processed" + $newpath + "\xml";
    [IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($newpath);
}
```

And of course you'll need to then execute your process.exe in that foreach loop.

Comment: No - sorry. Having it be a single line is a silly requirement. I removed that. A script would be fine. I will try this.