# Having Powershell Run in All Sub Directories

Tags: powershell, directory, imagemagick, subdirectory

So I'm building a script that will resize all photos within a directory using imagemagick but I want it to also run the script through all of the sub directories. I've tried a bunch of combinations but I can't seem to get it to work correctly so what can I add to this to make it run through the subdirectories?

```
$DIRECTORY = read-host -prompt 'PLEASE INPUT DIRECTORY'
$resize = "C:\imagekiller\resize.ps1"

cls
WRITE-HOST "WORKING, PLEASE WAIT..."

SET-LOCATION $DIRECTORY

mogrify -resize 960x528 *.jpg
mogrify -resize 960x528 *.png

WRITE-HOST = "----------DONE----------" -FOREGROUND "GREEN"

pause
cls
Invoke-Expression "$resize"
```

Comment: See [Run a simple command using PowerShell recursively on a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784057)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a simple command using PowerShell recursively on a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784057/run-a-simple-command-using-powershell-recursively-on-a-directory)

Comment: I've tried both of those but I seem to be having issues making them work.

Comment: @tylernol The answer is in the marked dupe and likely will be closed as such. I see no attempt to look at sub dirs in your question nor do you explain why the suggestion in the other comments does not work. What is not working exactly?

Comment: @matt Yes I pulled the scripts I've tried out of the question. These are the two I have tried: dir -recurse -include *.jpg | %{convert  $_.FullName -resize 620x620 "R:\processed\$_"}

Comment: $dir = dir c:\folder2shrink | ?{$_.PSISContainer}

foreach ($d in $dir){
    mogrify -resize 1024x768 *.jpg
    mogrify -resize 1024x768 *.png
}

Comment: both crash powershell even with debug on.

Comment: Crashed _how_ though? Code looks bad in comments. I would [edit] your question to include what you have tried. Your second example does not use `$d` which would contain the file you need

Comment: Try moving recurse to the end of the command  | -Recurse